# Showing 'Invalid Date' when comparing two dates and times in moment

Tags: javascript, reactjs, momentjs

I want to get time left when comparing between two dates and times. I have used moment library to format current date-time pair with coming date-time pair. See for example below:

```
var now = moment().format("Do MMM YYYY, h:mm A"); {/* <-- Current date-time pair */}

var newTime = "19th Apr 2021 9:30 PM";            {/* <-- Coming date-time pair */}

var duration = moment.utc(moment(now, "Do MM YYYY, h:mm A").diff(moment(newTime, "Do MM YYYY, h:mm A")))
               .format("h:mm");

return (
        <>
        {
           console.log('Time Left', duration)
        }
        </>
)
```

Getting error as 'Invalid Date' in console

What is the appropriate solution, to get time left between two date-time?

Following is the CodeSandbox link: https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-sn31v

After clicking the link, head on to timediff.js file

Comment: Your date format strings are not consistent, replace `MM` with `MMM` - even better create a single format string variable and use that instead of typing/copying the string several times

Comment: Also, no reason to convert `now` to a string and then parse it again.

Answer (score 0):

try srtting the dates with an array not a string. `moment([2021, 4, 19, 8, 30, 0])` as they do this in the docs aswell. i've tested it in your codesandbox and it works :)

https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/difference/

here is the fix: https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-kh7os?file=/timediff.js